# Что означает данная запись в sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть файл sql вот с таким содержимым

```
create table users
(
    chat_id   bigint            not null
        constraint users_pk
            primary key,
    username  text,
    full_name text,
    referral  integer,
    id        serial            not null,
    balance   integer default 0 not null
);

alter table users
    owner to postgres;

create unique index users_id_uindex
    on users (id);
```

Что означает ограничение `constraint users_pk` и строки

```
alter table users
    owner to postgres;

create unique index users_id_uindex
    on users (id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
chat_id bigint not null constraint users_pk primary key
```

Эта запись означает «создать колонку `chat_id`,
без нулей, с ограничением первичного ключа под названием
`users_pk`». Автор кода, наверное, хочет иметь
возможность позже изменить это ограничение и поэтому добавляет
ограничению известное имя.

```sql
alter table users owner to postgres
```

Здесь изменяется владелец таблицы. Таблица передаётся
пользователю `postgres`. Возможно,
чтобы исправить владение, если таблица создаётся из дампа
под другим пользователем.

```sql
create unique index users_id_uindex on users (id)
```

Здесь всё просто. Создаётся уникальный индекс
`users_id_uindex` на колонку `id`
таблицы `users`.

(Ну и да, всё это можно было поискать
в [документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/).)

Comment: А для чего необходимо создавать уникальный индекс, на что это влияет?

Answer (score 0):

1. `create table users` — создать пользователей таблиц
2. `alter table users` изменить пользователей таблицы владельца postgres
3. `create unique index` — создать уникальный индекс
4. `constraint users_pk` — хз, наверное блокирует

Уникальный индекс задаётся для того чтобы не было повторов значения `Id` к примеру  у вас есть юзер с `id-ом 54`,вы удаляете запись,уже юзера под `id-54` нету,следущий юзер будет не под `id 54` а уже под `id 55`